# How to re-sync photos from my iPhone to iCloud?

Tags: icloud, data-synchronization, storage

My iCloud storage got depleted because of my habit of never deleting photos. I’m on a free plan having 5GB of space and the iCloud reporting 4.7GB is taken by photos.

So, on my iPhone I’ve deleted several thousands photos and now on my phone I’ve got only 3GB of photos. But when I visit iCloud.com I can still see all those photos I've deleted.

How do I re-sync iCloud with what I’ve got on my phone?

I have an iPhone X with iOS version 13.1.2 on it (the latest one as per the time of writing). Most of the time I'm on a Wi-Fi connection (50mbps at home and 150mbps at work if that matters at all... I mean sync should be noticeable at the very least, it's not like 1 photo per minute).

Comment: Strongly suggest budgeting $12/year for the 50 GB iCloud plan. Your time manually deleting those photos is worth more. It's *really* nice if you have a "habit of never deleting photos."

Comment: @pkamb I usually don't like any subscriptions unless I absolutely have to... I don't even have direct debit set up for paying my rent (nor for any utility bills, internet, mobile, etc.), I always pay manually. I just... don't know.... I don't like services that automatically charge money from my account, not sure why... probably it gives me a sense of (imaginary) control..., but for the iCloud I believe you are right, I will look into that.

Comment: Do update the question if those answers don't address the problem. I was going to answer the way answer by user11633 was written too.

Comment: You can buy App Store gift cards with cash and use that as a "one-time payment" for the subscription.